# WCF service in Web Application

Tags: wcf

I have a web application( Using ASP.NET Web Application template). there i have created an WCF service (svc file). for testing purpose i just return a list of objects of my custom class. i added required attributes to custom class as well(DataContract) and for service class (ServiceContract) is added. i test it in browser, just access its url to make sure it working properly or not.

till here very thing is working fine. service seems working and being accessed from browser, so no error in service. when I try to consume this service in another web application, its reference is added successfully, give me the method too. but it doesn't return the values, my function at wcf side is returning `List<property>`. I get same count mean on wcf the function was returning List with 10 element and in web application where I'm consuming it is also show count 10 but the object within the list are empty.